# How to get data from Firestore based on date when the data type stored is timestamp(date and time)?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

You can see they are date and time in one field:

[image: You can see they are date and time in one field]

This is what the data look like when I click the field

[image: This is what the data look like when I click the field]

As you can see, `datetime` consist date and time, but I want to get data based on the date only

I've tried like this but didn't work

[image: I've tried like this but didn't work]

```
 private fun eventChangeListener() {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    val simpleDateFormat1 = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM D, yyyy")
    val dateTime1 = simpleDateFormat1.format(calendar.time).toString()
    Log.d("date2", dateTime1)

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val collection = db.collection("presensi")
    val query = collection
        .whereEqualTo("datetime", dateTime1)


    val option = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Dosen>()
        .setQuery(query, Dosen::class.java)
        .build()
    
    dosenAdapter = DosenAdapter(option)

    with(binding){
        tvNoData.visibility = View.GONE
        rvDosen.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        rvDosen.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rvDosen.adapter = dosenAdapter
    }
}
```

dateTime2 should print "January 24, 2023"

Is it actually possible to do that? or not?

Comment: Please add your code to your question!

Comment: I've added my code @MalikBilal

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the following query:

```
val query = collection
    .whereEqualTo("datetime", dateTime1)
```

It means that you're trying to get all documents from `presensi` collection, where the value of `datetime` field is equal to the value of `dateTime1`. This will not work because the `dateTime1` is a string while the `datetime` field in the database holds a Date object. To make it work, you need to pass to the `whereEqualTo()` method as the second argument a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object and **not** a string.

Comment: can you pls tell me how can I do that? I've remove the .toString from  val dateTime1 = simpleDateFormat1.format(calendar.time).toString() but still didn't work

Comment: hey now I use `currentTimeMillis()` then convert to timestamp using `val timeStamp = TimeStamp(currentTimeMillis)` and it seems to work but I only need the date so I can get data based on specific date how do I do that?

Comment: You have to pass a Date object that is exactly like the one you have in your database to actually have a match. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: now I use timestamp like this `  val startOfDay = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
        val dateTime4 = Timestamp(startOfDay)
      


        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val collection = db.collection("presensi")
        val query = collection

            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("datetime", dateTime4)
            .orderBy("datetime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)




        val option = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Dosen>()
            .setQuery(query, Dosen::class.java)
            .build()`

Comment: not really the way I want but yes it does work

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: no thank you, all good